# Porque as strings que contêm [ ou ] vindas de $_POST são transformadas em array?

Tags: php, ajax, post

Estou mandando dados de um textArea via AJAX para o PHP pelo método POST. nesse textarea contém alguns colchetes. Pois bem, quando o texto do textArea chega no POST, ele automaticamente transforma o conteúdo que tem desses colchetes em outro array, no que deveria apenas retornar uma string comum. VEJA:

```
    let textareaValue = "isso é um teste [e isso também]";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open('POST', '../controller/test.php', true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return;
   console.log(req.responseText);
   };
req.send(textareaValue);
```

RESULTADO NO PHP:

```
echo $_POST;
 /* output 
array(1) {
  ["isso_é_um_teste_"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["e isso também"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque você está usando `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

---

O `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` deveria ser:

```
var=valor&var2=valor2 (...)
```

No caso o PHP também entende como array se fizer:

```
var["index"]=valor&var["outroIndex"]=outroValor
```

---

No seu caso você tem:

```
isso é um teste [e isso também]
```

Então isso seria o mesmo que fazer (equivalente à `isso é um teste [e isso também]=`), então:

```
"isso é um teste" => var
[e isso também]   => ["index"]
                  => valor
```

---

Há duas formas de resolver o problema:

---

1. **Altere o content-type:**

Altere o content-type:

```
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Para:

```
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Além disso, obtenha o resultado no PHP usando `file_get_contents('php://input');`, ao invés do `$_POST`.

---

2. **Altere o corpo da requisição para atender ao urlenceded**

Se quiser ainda usar o `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` dê um nome para variável, como:

```
 let textareaValue = "x=isso é um teste [e isso também]";
```

Então leia o `$_POST["x"]`.

Comment: sensacional! É isso ai mesmo. valeu!